# How can I store an Array or a list by using PlayerPrefsx

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I've found something like this: "PlayerPrefsX, ArrayPrefs"
 on : http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=ArrayPrefs2, but they doesn't exist when I typed them in my monoDevelop editor, anyone help?

Comment: Try to click the `Assets->Sync MonoDevelop Project` and restart MonoDevelop to try again? Sometimes it is just not sync with the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ArrayPrefs script is not included by default into unity or a standard assets package. If you want to use it, create source files `PlayerPrefsX.js` or `PlayerPrefsX.cs` and fill their content with source you've found on the unity3d wiki link. Then you will be able to start using them in the editor (you may need to sync your project as it was mentioned above).